# How to add translation of all content?

Tags: 8, nodes, i18n-l10n

I am adding Arabic translations to an English website. For every article node, I need to individually translate each node.

Is there a way to add translations in one go?

The customer will update the content, but I need to create the initial translation of more than 500 nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all nodes, then with a foreach create a translation for each node.

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityQuery("node")
//->condition('type', 'my_custom_type') //use this for specific content types
->execute();

$nodes =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  //Creating the translation Spanish in this case
  $node_es = $node->addTranslation('es');
  $node_es->title = 'Mi prueba!';
  $node_es->body->value = '<p>El cuerpo de mi nodo.</p>';
  $node_es->body->format = 'full_html';
  //Saving the node
  $node_es->save();
}
```

You can add some fields like title and body, or just save.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, If I want to copy all the content in translated node, then any way to do that?

Comment: Actually if you don't update any field it should copy all content, so  do addTranslation then save.